# Web Api 2 not returning ByteArrayContent to HTTPClient

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I am putting together a test application using WebApi2 and HttpClient in a win forms app.

I have come accross an issue where my HttpClient request to a WebApi2 controller which returns an HttpResponseMessage doesnt return the ByteArrayContent.
WebApiController Code

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFilePart(string fileName)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/" + fileName);
    var fileArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new  ByteArrayContent(fileArray)
    };

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileArray.Length;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = fileName
    };

    return response;
}
```

WinForms Code using HttpClient

```
static async void GetFilePart(string hostrUri)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(hostrUri)
    };

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/Home/DownloadFilePart/?fileName=Test.txt");
    var responseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var stream = await responseMessage.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    var fileToWriteTo = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Temp\\Test.txt";

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //copy the content from response to filestream
        fileStream.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);
    }
}
```

When the request return from the WebApi and I write the bytes to file all that is written into the file is the actual headers from the WebApi response. Has anyone any ideas what the issue could be here?

Thanks

Comment: First suggestion would be to add an await here: `var responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync...`, then you don't need `.Result` later, which is a blocking (potentially deadlock-causing) call.

Comment: Can you hit the API endpoint from a browser and download the correct file contents? That should tell you whether the problem is with the Web API code or the WinForms code. At a glance I'm not spotting the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` is summarized as

> The operation should complete as soon as a response is available and headers are read. **The content is not read yet**.

This would explain why you only get the headers in your response.

Either remove it completely or change it to `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead`

```
static async void GetFilePart(string hostrUri)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(hostrUri)
    };

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/Home/DownloadFilePart/?fileName=Test.txt");
    var responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    var byteArray = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    var fileToWriteTo = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\Temp\\Test.txt";

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //copy the content from response to filestream
        fileStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
}
```